# Convert 64 bit unsigned int to char buffer back and forth in C

Tags: c, string, 64-bit

My aim is to send a datagram over a network that starts with 64 bit unsigned integer in network byte order. So first I use macros to transform the number into big-endian:

```
#define htonll(x) ((1==htonl(1)) ? (x) : ((uint64_t)htonl((x) & 0xFFFFFFFF) << 32) | htonl((x) >> 32))
#define ntohll(x) ((1==ntohl(1)) ? (x) : ((uint64_t)ntohl((x) & 0xFFFFFFFF) << 32) | ntohl((x) >> 32))
```

Then I serialize it into a buffer:

```
unsigned char * serialize_uint64(unsigned char *buffer, uint64_t value) {
  printf("**** seriializing PRIu64 value = %"PRIu64"\n", value);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    buffer[i] = (value >> (56 - 8 * i)) & 0xFF;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("bufer[%d] = %x\n", i, buffer[i]);

  return buffer + 8;
}
```

Then I deserializes it with

```
uint64_t deserialize_uint64(unsigned char *buffer) {
  uint64_t res = 0;
  printf("*** deserializing buffer:\n");
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    printf("bufer[%d] = %x\n", i, buffer[i]);
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    res |= buffer[i] << (56 - 8 * i);


  return res;
}
```

It seems to work for small integers but the following test code is not working properly:

```
uint64_t a = (uint64_t) time(NULL);
printf("PRIu64: a =%"PRIu64"\n", a);

uint64_t z = htonll(a);
uint64_t zz = ntohll(z);
printf("z = %"PRIu64" ==> zz = %"PRIu64" \n", z, zz);

unsigned char buffer[1024];
serialize_uint64(buffer, z);
uint64_t b = deserialize_uint64(buffer);
uint64_t c = ntohll(g);
```

as I get

```
a = 1494157850
htonll(a) = 1876329069679738880 ==> ntohll(htonll(a)) = 1494157850 
**** seriializing PRIu64 value = 1876329069679738880
bufer[0] = 1a
bufer[1] = a
bufer[2] = f
bufer[3] = 59
bufer[4] = 0
bufer[5] = 0
bufer[6] = 0
bufer[7] = 0
*********
*** deserializing buffer:
bufer[0] = 1a
bufer[1] = a
bufer[2] = f
bufer[3] = 59
bufer[4] = 0
bufer[5] = 0
bufer[6] = 0
bufer[7] = 0
===> res = 436866905
c = 6417359100811673600
```

It seems like the buffer is not capturing the bigger number ...

Comment: Edit: it works well for 32bit so up to `2,147,483,647` but it crashes for `2,147,483,648`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serializer is essentially

```
unsigned char *serialize_u64(unsigned char *buffer, uint64_t value)
{
    buffer[7] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[6] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[5] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[4] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[2] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[1] = value & 0xFF;
    value >>= 8;
    buffer[0] = value & 0xFF;
    return buffer + 8;
}
```

and it serializes `value` from native byte order to network byte order; no macro is needed.

So, it looks like OP's `serialize_uint64()` should work just fine. It's just that no byte order macro should be used at all.

OP's `deserialize_uint64()` should cast `buffer[i]` to `(uint64_t)` before shifting, to ensure the shifted result is 64-bit. Personally, I prefer to write the deserializer as

```
unsigned char *serialize_u64(unsigned char *buffer, uint64_t *valueptr)
{
    uint64_t value = buffer[0];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[1];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[2];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[3];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[4];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[5];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[6];
    value <<= 8;
    value |= buffer[7];
    *valueptr = value;
    return buffer + 8;
}
```

which does the equivalent operation as OP's, if OP used `res |= ((uint64_t)buffer[i]) << (56 - 8 * i);` instead.

Again, both serializer and deserializer already convert the data to/from network byte order from/to native byte order; no byte order macros should be used at all.

Comment: Casting to `uint64_t` has helped - many thanks! But on byte order macro - if I want this to be portable and I don't know what the endianness of the running machine is I need to somehow differentiate that - is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @micsza: Yes, you are missing something. As I explained, the code shown converts `value` from/to native byte order to/from network byte order. It does not matter what the native byte order is. The code itself is perfectly portable.

Comment: @micsza: As to exactly why no byte order conversion is needed, we need to look at the math involved. In network byte order, the first byte of a value is the most significant one; for a 64-bit value, it contains bits 56 to 63, inclusive. The math the functions implement, extract this and the other byte values directly from the 64-bit value, using bit shifting and masking. The native byte order is irrelevant, because the math done on the 64-bit value does not depend on the native byte order at all.